# TSQL PIVOT [Year], COUNT(SalesPeople), and GROUP BY [Territory]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, pivot, grouping

From the AdventureWorks database, I'm trying to return total sales per year by territory, and include how many sales people are active in each territory. The below code fails to group by territory, and instead creates a unique row for each sales person. What is my code missing?

**Desired Result**

```
| SalesTerritory | SalesPeople | 2011   | 2012    | 2013    | 2014    |
+----------------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Australia      | 1           | NULL   | NULL    | 184105  | 1237705 |
| Canada         | 2           | 115360 | 3426082 | 2568323 | etc...  |
```

**Code**

```
SELECT
     pvt.SalesTerritory
    ,COUNT(pvt.SalesPersonID) AS SalesPeople
    ,pvt.[2011]
    ,pvt.[2012]
    ,pvt.[2013]
    ,pvt.[2014]
FROM    (SELECT
            st.[Name] AS [SalesTerritory]
            ,soh.[SalesPersonID]
            ,soh.[SubTotal]
            ,YEAR(DATEADD(m, 6, soh.[OrderDate])) AS [FiscalYear]
         FROM   [Sales].[SalesPerson] sp
            INNER JOIN  [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] soh
                ON sp.[BusinessEntityID] = soh.[SalesPersonID]
            INNER JOIN  [Sales].[SalesTerritory] st
                ON sp.[TerritoryID] = st.[TerritoryID]
            INNER JOIN  [HumanResources].[Employee] e
                ON soh.[SalesPersonID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
            INNER JOIN  [Person].[Person] p
                ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = sp.[BusinessEntityID]) AS soh
PIVOT
    (
    SUM([SubTotal]) FOR [FiscalYear] IN ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])
    ) AS pvt
GROUP BY    pvt.SalesTerritory
            ,[2011]
            ,[2012]
            ,[2013]
            ,[2014];
```

**Actual Result**

```
| SalesTerritory | SalesPeople | 2011   | 2012    | 2013    | 2014    |
+----------------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Australia      | 1           | NULL   | NULL    | 184105  | 1237705 |
| Canada         | 1           | 9109   | 1254087 | 1179530 | 1166720 |
| Canada         | 1           | 106251 | 2171995 | 1388793 | etc...  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sum the subtotals in the upper most query and group by only SalesTerritory.

see the below

```
SELECT
     pvt.SalesTerritory
    ,COUNT(pvt.SalesPersonID) AS SalesPeople
    ,sum(pvt.[2011])
    ,sum(pvt.[2012])
    ,sum(pvt.[2013])
    ,sum(pvt.[2014])
FROM    (SELECT
            st.[Name] AS [SalesTerritory]
            ,soh.[SalesPersonID]
            ,soh.[SubTotal]
            ,YEAR(DATEADD(m, 6, soh.[OrderDate])) AS [FiscalYear]
         FROM   [Sales].[SalesPerson] sp
            INNER JOIN  [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] soh
                ON sp.[BusinessEntityID] = soh.[SalesPersonID]
            INNER JOIN  [Sales].[SalesTerritory] st
                ON sp.[TerritoryID] = st.[TerritoryID]
            INNER JOIN  [HumanResources].[Employee] e
                ON soh.[SalesPersonID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
            INNER JOIN  [Person].[Person] p
                ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = sp.[BusinessEntityID]) AS soh
PIVOT
    (
    SUM([SubTotal]) FOR [FiscalYear] IN ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])
    ) AS pvt
GROUP BY    pvt.SalesTerritory
```